# Keras not training on entire dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

So I've been following Google's official tensorflow guide and trying to build a simple neural network using Keras. But when it comes to training the model, it does not use the entire dataset (with 60000 entries) and instead uses only 1875 entries for training. Any possible fix?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

class_names = ['T-shirt', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle Boot']

model = keras.Sequential([
                          keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
                          keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'), 
                          keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss= tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3183 - accuracy: 0.8866
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3169 - accuracy: 0.8873
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3144 - accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3130 - accuracy: 0.8885
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3110 - accuracy: 0.8883
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3090 - accuracy: 0.8888
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3073 - accuracy: 0.8895
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3057 - accuracy: 0.8900
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3040 - accuracy: 0.8905
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3025 - accuracy: 0.8915

<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fbe0e5aebe0>
```

Here's the original google colab notebook where I've been working on this: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NdtzXHEpiNnelcMaJeEm6zmp34JMcN38

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The number `1875` shown during fitting the model is not the training samples; it is the number of *batches*.

`model.fit` includes an optional argument `batch_size`, which, according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit):

> If unspecified, `batch_size` will default to 32.

So, what happens here is - you fit with the default batch size of 32 (since you have not specified anything different), so the total number of batches for your data is

```
60000/32 = 1875
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not train on 1875 samples.

```
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [===
```

1875 here is the number of steps, not samples. In `fit` method, there is an argument, `batch_size`. The default value for it is `32`. So `1875*32=60000`. The implementation is correct.

If you train it with `batch_size=16`, you will see the number of steps will be `3750` instead of `1875`, since `60000/16=3750`.

Comment: This is definitely not as simple as its just doing the epoch in batches, on this sample in the OP, setting the batch to 60000 makes it incredibly fast, yet horribly accurate. Likely this is tied to implementation details, my guess is that only 1 run of the loss and optimizer is being ran after each batch, and most guides are tied to the older versions,  which likely have the optimizer and loss run each single input.

Answer (score -2):

Just use batch_size = 1, if you want the entire 60000 data samples to be visible.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.