# model using only the first sample of the dataset to train

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm training the following model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=30, output_dim=64, mask_zero=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=1024)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="sigmoid"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="linear")
])
```

This network deals with text, so I turned each string of my dataset into a numpy array by converting each letter to a numeric value:

```
def converter(fen):
    normal_list = []

    for letter in fen:
        if letter == "/" or letter == " " or letter == "-":
            normal_list.append(0)
        elif letter == "p":
            normal_list.append(1)
        elif letter == "P":
            normal_list.append(2)
        elif letter == "n":
            normal_list.append(3)
        elif letter == "N":
            normal_list.append(4)
        elif letter == "b":
            normal_list.append(5)
        elif letter == "B":
            normal_list.append(6)
        elif letter == "r":
            normal_list.append(7)
        elif letter == "R":
            normal_list.append(8)
        elif letter == "q":
            normal_list.append(9)
        elif letter == "Q":
            normal_list.append(10)
        elif letter == "k":
            normal_list.append(11)
        elif letter == "K":
            normal_list.append(12)
        elif letter == "a":
            normal_list.append(13)
        elif letter == "b":
            normal_list.append(14)
        elif letter == "c":
            normal_list.append(15)
        elif letter == "d":
            normal_list.append(16)
        elif letter == "e":
            normal_list.append(17)
        elif letter == "f":
            normal_list.append(18)
        elif letter == "g":
            normal_list.append(19)
        elif letter == "h":
            normal_list.append(20)
        elif letter == "1":
            normal_list.append(21)
        elif letter == "2":
            normal_list.append(22)
        elif letter == "3":
            normal_list.append(23)
        elif letter == "4":
            normal_list.append(24)
        elif letter == "5":       
            normal_list.append(25) 
        elif letter == "6":
            normal_list.append(26)
        elif letter == "7":
            normal_list.append(27)
        elif letter == "8":
            normal_list.append(28)
        elif letter == "9":
            normal_list.append(29)
        else:
            normal_list.append(0)
    
    return np.array(normal_list, ndmin=2).astype(np.float32)
    # I used ndmin = 2 because the embedding layer turns it into ndmin = 3
```

Then I imported the dataset for training converting the samples:

```
x_set = []
y_set = []

for position in df["position"]:
    x_set.append(cvt.converter(position))
```

The `len(x_set)` is 950, and the `x_set[0].shape` is (1, ?) where ? varies between 50 and 70.

About the `y_set`, I used:

```
for a in range(len(df["position"])):
    y_set.append(np.array([
        df["Pawns"][a], df["Knights"][a], df["Bishops"][a], df["Rooks"][a],
        df["Queens"][a], df["Mobility"][a], df["King"][a], df["Threats"][a],
        df["Passed"][a], df["Space"][a]
    ], ndmin=2)) # If I don't use ndmin = 2 here I get ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous
```

And its len is also 950

When I call `model.fit(x_set, y_set, epochs = 10)` the model only uses one sample to train the net:

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 19s 19s/step - loss: 0.2291 - mae: 0.4116
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.1645 - mae: 0.3302
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.0764 - mae: 0.1982
Epoch 4/10
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 1.4347 - mae: 1.0087
Epoch 5/10
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.0038 - mae: 0.0461
Epoch 6/10
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.0532 - mae: 0.1780
Epoch 7/10
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.0597 - mae: 0.1931
Epoch 8/10
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.0522 - mae: 0.1814
Epoch 9/10
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.0375 - mae: 0.1583
Epoch 10/10
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.0252 - mae: 0.1432
```

Shouldn't it be using all of 950 samples of x_set? What is wrong in this code?

Comment: mode is getting trained on full data set i.e 950 over 10 times if there is a need then batch size can be utilized. i don't think it using only one sample, where you noticed this?

Comment: `1` here means 1 batch, not 1 sample; see [Keras not training on entire dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122276/keras-not-training-on-entire-dataset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line indicates it's training on one batch, not one sample:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 19s 19s/step - loss: 0.2291 - mae: 0.4116
```

The default batch_size in Keras is 32, I believe.  A Keras embedding layer expects integers, not floats, and you're using too many dimensions, so you should change this line in your converter:

```py
return np.array(normal_list, ndmin=2).astype(np.float32)
```

To this:

```py
return np.array(normal_list)
```

You want each training sample to have a shape of (?), where ? is 50-70 in your case.  You want each target to have a shape of (10), because your model is outputting 10 values from its last dense layer.  Combined with the number of samples, you want `x_set` to have a shape of `(950, ?)` and `y_set` to have a shape of `(950, 10)`.  To avoid issues, you should probably pad all of your samples to have the same size instead of varying between 50 and 70.

Your model expects this input:

```py
>>> model.input_shape
(None, None)
```

Your `model.summary()` is as follows (the first `None` dimension is the batch_size, which in your case is 950):

```py
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_2 (Embedding)      (None, None, 64)          1920      
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 2048)              8921088   
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               262272    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1290      
=================================================================
Total params: 9,186,570
Trainable params: 9,186,570
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

In short, you're embedding your entire training set into a single sample, I believe.